# S3 GET without Signing (Cleartext possible?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to GET a object from Amazon S3 by sending the cleartext Accesskey:Secret instead of signing/HMAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless the ACL is set for anonymous read access.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use Amazon S3 query string authentication with your URL. Most Amazon S3 clients can generate that.

You can also use an [S3fm](http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3fm/index.html), an online file manager for Amazon S3. Just select Web URL in your context menu and generate an URL with an expiration date.